# my php code is only importing the first line of my csv file to the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv, fgetcsv

So, i have a csv file that i want to import to the database but its only importing the first line.
i dont know why its not importing all the data in my csv file.
maybe because of the line breaks?

Sample of My CSV file:

"Tiago" <20>,20,11,sip/11,20,w,2016-03-01 14:33:06,2016-03-01 14:33:09,2016-03-01 14:33:51,45
"Claudio" <10>,10,11,sip/11,20,w,2016-03-01 14:35:05,2016-03-01 14:35:07,2016-03-01 14:35:48,43
"Hortencio" <11>,11,21,sip/21,20,w,2016-03-01 14:39:55,2016-03-01 14:40:12,2016-03-01 14:40:25,30
"Andre" <19>,19,22,22000@default,s,2016-03-01 14:43:22,2016-03-01 14:43:42,2016-03-01 14:43:42,20

My model:

```
<?php

class Csv_model extends CI_Model {

var $gallery_path;
var $gallery_path_url;
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();


    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../csv');
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url() . 'csv/';
}

function do_upload($data) {
        $filename = $data['fileinfo'][0];
        $path = $data['fileinfo'][1];
        ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('csv_form', $error);
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('csv_success', $data);
            $linecount=count(file($path.''.$filename.'.csv'));

            $file = fopen($path.''.$filename.'.csv', "r");

            $csv = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",", ' ');
            fclose($file);


            $n = 0;
            echo $l=$linecount;
            function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'){
                 $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
                 return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
            }
            for($i = 0; $i <= $l && $n < $l; $i++){

                $insert_csv = array();

                $insert_csv['clid'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;
                $insert_csv['src'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;
                $insert_csv['dst'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;
                $insert_csv['dstchannel'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;
                if(is_numeric($csv[$n])){
                    echo 'yes';
                $insert_csv['numero'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;
                }else{
                echo"ok";
                $insert_csv['numero'] = " ";}
                if(ctype_alpha($csv[$n])){
                $insert_csv['w'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;
                }else{
                $insert_csv['w'] = " ";
                echo"ok";}
                $insert_csv['start'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;
                $insert_csv['answer'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;
                if(validateDate($csv[$n])){
                $insert_csv['end'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;
                }else{
                $insert_csv['end'] = " ";}
                if($csv[$n] == 0){
                $insert_csv['duration'] = " ";
                $n++;}else{
                $insert_csv['duration'] = $csv[$n];
                $n++;}


                $data1 = array(
                'clid' => $insert_csv['clid'],
                'src' => $insert_csv['src'],
                'dst' => $insert_csv['dst'],
                'dstchannel' => $insert_csv['dstchannel'],
                'numero' => $insert_csv['numero'],
                'w' => $insert_csv['w'],    
                'start' => $insert_csv['start'],
                'answer' => $insert_csv['answer'],
                'end' => $insert_csv['end'],
                'duration' => $insert_csv['duration']);

                $this->db->insert('chamadas', $data1);

            }
            echo 'Success!!!';
            $success['success'] = "success";
            return $success;

        }
} 

function get_all()
    {
        return $this->db->get('chamadas')->result_array();
    }

}
```

Comment: `$linecount=count(file($path.''.$filename.'.csv'));` will always be equal to `1`. It's just counting the number of entries in the array, which is one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You have to loop over each line to read the whole file, otherwise you're only reading the first line in the file

`

```
$file = fopen($path.''.$filename.'.csv', "r");
$csv = array();  
while (($csv = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",", ' ')) !== FALSE) 
{
   $n[] = $csv;
}
fclose($file);
```

`

Comment: thanks for the help i solved it if your code thanks now it gives all the data

Comment: just need to know to import to database now

Comment: You should write "INSERT" Query inside the loop

Comment: if someone want i can post the final solution